# Get Hierarchical Data from Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello i have one stupid question. But maybe is not.
In database i have table **categories** and i have 4 cols 
Id, parent_id, title and description.
Parent_id is child of current category.

```
Id |  parent_id |  title  |  description

___________________________________________________

1  |     1      | Main Category | description 


2  |     1      | Sub Category  | description 


3  |     2      | Other Category | description 

4  |     1      | Some Category | description
```

Ok i know how to input data and show results; that is not problem. When i show result in table

```
<table>
   <tr>
        <td> Id </td>
        <td> Parent </td>
        <td> Title </td>
        <td> Desc </td>
   </tr>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <tr>
       <td> <?php echo $category->id; ?> </td>
       <td> <?php echo $category->parent_id; ?> </td>
       <td> <?php echo $category->title; ?> </td>
       <td> <?php echo $category->eescription; ?> </td>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

This works great and shows child categories under under the other parent categories : Table looks like this:

```
1  |     1      | Main Category | description 
2  |     1      | Sub Category  | description   
3  |     2      | Other Category | description    
4  |     1      | Some Category | description
```

My problem is how to list all category and sub category like this

```
    |-- Main Category
       |--- Sub Category 
           |--- One more cat  

   |--Other Category   
      |--- Some Category
```

Like this
[image]

Is it possible to fetch this data using forach() ? Any example how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about this http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/. Should solve your issue.

Comment: Tell me one, i understand tutorial from site. But am confused bcs he say root category is empty. What database col type i must set for that col? My type is INT and when is emty default value is 0. On tutorial he say must be empty.

Comment: Parent field must be empty at the top. Usually no one uses top category. It is sort of an abstract parent and from there you start creating catalog/category navigation.

Comment: @Eugene I understand the tutorial, but they have given left and right values directly. How could I know left and right values while adding node as child or parent.

Answer (score 1):

I do this. Am working on Codeigniter framework. If any need this i will post how i fix this like on screenshot.

Just simple make model :

Model

```
   /*
    * Get all children categories
    * 
    * Get Hierarchical Data from Categories
    * 
    * @ikac
    */

   public function fetchChildren($parent, $level) {


       $this->handler = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM content_categories WHERE parent='".$parent."' ");


          foreach($this->handler->result() as $row) {
             echo str_repeat('&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; |-----', $level).$row->title .'<br>';

             $this->fetchChildren($row->title, $level+1);
          }

   }

}
```

Like output u will get

```
Default
     |-----Sub Category
     |-----Test Category 1
           |-----Seccond Test Category 1
```

Thanks @Eugene